# Extract the date in PowerAutomate

Tags: power-automate, date-time, conversion

When a user pastes a email (`.EML`) file in a document library in SharePoint, a Power Automate flow should extract the reception date from that email. In the MIME type, the date is like:

```
Date: Thu, 2 Jun 2016 13:41:23 +0000
```

Is there a way to extract such a line with Power Automate, I recall the MIME format:
[image]

It does not seem to support regex.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `formatDateTime` and `parseDateTime`.
Considering a variable `MyDateAsText`, use this formula to get the date:

```
formatDateTime(parseDateTime(slice(variables('MyDateAsText'), add(indexOf(variables('MyDateAsText'), ' '), 1), nthIndexOf(variables('MyDateAsText'), ' ', 5))), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

[image: cloud flow]
[image: date extracted]

Do you know the feature `Format data by examples`? It's great feature to generate formula with an input and a desired output. You should try!

[image: format by example]

Comment: for me, the most complicated is to extract the date as string, I didn't get yet to convert the text to a date, but even to capture the date from the file is complicated, without regex. I have the .EML file, I need a) to extract the date string, b) to convert the string to a date.

Comment: Did you try `Format data by examples`? It's just extracting a lien from a text. Why formula did you used? Please try before asking.